# how to store the switch state in firebase database in android

Tags: android, firebase, location

I am trying to save the switch state in the firebase database when i change the state of the switch data store correct but the switch state automatic change back to the previous state **strong text**

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.